# Какой частью речи является слово "намусорено" в предложении "На улице намусорено"?

Tags: части-речи

**"На улице холодно"** – в этом предложении *"холодно"* - категория состояния.

Будет ли и *"намусорено"* категорией состояния в предложении **"На улице намусорено?"**, и не нужно ли тогда писать две Н (ведь в полной форме две Н: *"намусоренный"*)?

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос, он интересный.  Пишется одна буква Н, но нужно правильно объяснить. // Это уже ваш четвертый вопрос, но нет ни одного принятого. Чем вас не устроили предыдущие ответы?

Comment: @Sharon я слежу за своими предыдущими вопросами, но исчерпывающих ответов пока не увидел, к сожалению. (А один из них так и висит без ответа.)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, информация понятна. А можно еще спросить: вы на других ресурсах задаете вопросы? Просто хочется сравнить уровень отвечающих, ну и оценить качество нашего форума.

Comment: @Sharon нет, только здесь

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: *На  улице ***намусорено***.* Одна буква ***Н***.

**Пояснение**

1. Сравнить:

*На улице **намусорили*** (неопределенно-личное предложение).

*На улице **холодно*** (безличное предложение, слово категории состояния; также предикатив, безлично-предикативное слово).

2. Это односоставное **безличное** предложение. Часть речи — **краткое страдательное причастие**, одна буква Н. Здесь выражено значение **действия** (кто-то намусорил).
3. Это **не слово** категории состояния, то есть самого  "состояния" нет. Но такие формы **сходны** со словами категории состояния. Иногда их называют **причастные** предикативы.
4. **Семантика** слов категории состояния такова: состояние **природы или человека**, модальные, оценочные, количественные значения и т.д. **Субъект-лицо** выражается Д.п. (ему холодно), на **субъект-носитель** состояния может указывать обстоятельственный детерминант (где).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Хочу уточнить, что означает в вашем ответе "д.п."? И еще на этом сайте такие причастия тоже отнесли к КС: "слова, соотносимые по грамматической форме с краткими страдательными причастиями среднего рода: обнаружено, указано, накурено, решено, выяснено, заперто"
Источник: https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/kategoriia-sostoianiia.html – это, я так понимаю, ошибка?

Comment: Д.п. — дательный падеж. // Я даю материал по вузовским учебникам.  Основными способами выражения главного члена безличного предложения являются: (1) безличный глагол; (2) слово категории состояния; (3) слово нет и глагол быть с отрицанием; (4) краткое страдательное причастие (причастный предикатив).  Поэтому надо различать слова категории состояния и причастные предикативы.

Comment: Накурено — это  слово категории состояния: НАКУРЕНО, нареч., в функц. сказ. (где). О наличии дыма от курения; о сильном запахе табачного дыма в помещении. Н. табаком, махоркой. Здесь очень н.!  Остальные — причастные предикативы.

Answer (score 0):

Второй ответ

Проверка по словарям **не подтверждает** версию о существовании причастного предикатива ***намусорено***.

1. **В [словаре](https://gramota.ru/meta/namusorit)** нет причастия для глагола ***намусорить.***  А его и не может быть, так как глагол **непереходный:** от него нельзя образовать страд. причастие  прошедшего времени.

**НАМУСОРИТЬ**, -рю, -ришь; св. (нсв. мусорить). Разг. Набросать мусору; насорить. Н. в комнате. Н. на полу.

2. Тогда ***намусорено*** –  слово **категории состояния**, как и ***накурено.*** (также образовано от непер. глагола, **нет** причастных форм).

**НАКУРИТЬ**, -курю, -куришь; накуренный; -рен, -а, -о; св. 1. **(чем).** Куря, наполнить помещение табачным дымом. Н. табаком, махоркой. // **чем.** Сжигая какое-л. ароматическое вещество, наполнить помещение ароматным дымом, запахом. Н. ладаном. Н. благовониями.

**НАКУРЕНО**, нареч., **в функц. сказ**. (где). О наличии дыма от курения; о сильном запахе табачного дыма в помещении. Н. табаком, махоркой. Здесь очень н.!

3. Краткие формы прилагательных могут писаться с одной ***Н*** по образцу причастий. В словаре для слов категории состояния указывается: **в функц. сказ**. Кроме того, причастия ***накуренный*** нет, как нет и прилагательного ***накуренный***  в полной форме.
4. **Пример** (**однородные** отношения с прилагательным):

Владимир Лавришко. Один день из жизни Очень Знаменитого Поэта // «Октябрь», 2001

*Очень Знаменитый Поэт повернул ключ, распахнул дверь, щелкнул выключателем — в номере было как-то особенно, по-гостиничному, пусто, **накурено и намусорено**.*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А разве "накурить" – непереходный глагол? ("Накурить кого/что? комнату")

Comment: Это непереходный глагол в основном значении (но переходный во втором значении).   У переходного глагола обозначено управление ЧТО,  а здесь  управление ЧЕМ, то есть наполнить (чем?) дымом помещение.  НАКУРИТЬ, св. 1. (чем). Куря, наполнить помещение табачным дымом. Н. табаком, махоркой. // чем. Сжигая какое-л. ароматическое вещество, наполнить помещение ароматным дымом, запахом. Н. ладаном. Н. благовониями. 2. что и чего. Добыть, приготовить в каком-л. количестве путём перегонки (курения). Н. вина (устар.; о водке). Н. бочку смолы. Накуривать, -нсв.

Comment: А можете дать ссылку про "Краткие формы прилагательных могут писаться с одной Н по образцу причастий"? Хочется до конца разобраться... Спасибо!

Comment: Это  Розенталь §48, пункт 7 и 8; ПАС под ред.Лопатина § 102.  В этой теме лучше всего ориентироваться на словарь РАН,  фактически дан даны все ответы. Например:  Русский орфографический словарь
насыщенный; кр. ф. прич. -ен, -ена; кр. ф. прил. -ен, -ена (с дополн.: жизнь насыщена приключениями) и -ен, -енна (без дополн.: жизнь насыщенна, содержательна) https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=насыщенный&mode=slovari&l=1&dicts[]=71

Comment: Вот по нашей теме: НАКУРЕНО  накурено, в знач. сказ.  https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=накурено&mode=all&l=1  https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=насорено&mode=slovari&l=1&dicts[]=71  Это не причастия, а краткие формы прилагательных в значении категории состояния.

Comment: Здесь указывают на то, что это все-таки предикативы, несмотря на непереходность глаголов: "... В лингвистических словарях современного р. я. такие слова, как правило, снабжены пометой «в знач. сказ.» или пометой «предик.», однако они, несомненно, сохраняют связь с мотивирущими основами причастий и, соответственно, глаголов. Обращает на себя внимание тот факт, что некоторые из этих предикативов образованы от непереходных глаголов. Ср.: накурено < накурить, наплевано < наплевать, насорено < насорить

http://tinyurl.com/yx253rvz

Comment: Вам нужно разобраться с определениями, которые вы используете (то есть как вы их понимаете, правильно ли вы их понимаете).  Вот ответ Грамоты, который может быть вами интересен:  в чём разница понятий ПРЕДИКАТ и ПРЕДИКАТИВ?  https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=предикатив&mode=spravka#:~:text=Предикат%20–%201)%20понятие%2C%20определяющее,нединамическое%20состояние%2C%20например%3A%20Надо%20ехать  В словарях  про предикативы обычно пишут: употребл. в значении сказ.

Comment: Латинский по происхождению суффикс ИВ тоже интересен:  В заимствованных словах (обычно латинского происхождения) сохраняются суффиксы īv-us, a, um в значении «пригодный, служащий для чего-либо, содержащий».https://vk.com/wall-189365070_11466   По теме можно прочитать статью  http://rusgram.ru/Предикатив